# Reasons behind targeting multiple frameworks?

Tags: .net, version

I'm see a lot of projects which releases, for example, library for multiple .net FX-es (2.0, 3.5, 4.0). Is there any major reasons to target multiple FX **if code will be the same** (no questions if code is different, of course)?

Also, in my opinion, the lower the FX version, the more possibilities to use library in projects there target FX version can't go up for some reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big reason would be down to the user's machine and the version of the .NET runtime they have installed. By targetting the lowest common denominator, you can ensure you get maximum reach and compatibility.